# Understanding the sliding law of MonadFix

Tags: haskell, monads, monadfix

I intuitively understand the purity, tightening, and nesting laws of [`MonadFix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Fix.html). However, I'm having a hard time understanding the sliding law.

```hs
mfix (fmap h . f) = fmap h (mfix (f . h)) -- for strict h
```

My first question is that if `h` has to be strict then won't `mfix (f . h)` be  the bottom value , i.e. `⊥`? After all, `f . h` must not inspect its input until after it returns, so that it doesn't cause a paradox. However, if `h` is strict then it will have to inspect its input. Perhaps my understanding of a strict function is wrong.

Second, why is this law important? I can understand the significance of the purity, tightening, and nesting laws. However, I don't see why it would be important for `mfix` to obey the sliding law. Could you provide a code example which demonstrates why the sliding law is important for `MonadFix`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't fully explain the law, but I think I can provide some insight.

Let's forget about the monadic part of that equation, and let's pretend that `f,h :: A -> A` are plain, non-monadic functions. The law then simplifies (informally speaking) to the following:

```
fix (h . f) = h (fix (f . h))
```

This is a well-known property in fixed point theory I [discussed in CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/84721/y-combinator-function-composition/84772#84772) some time ago.

The informal intuition, though, is that the least fixed point for `g :: A->A` is something that can be written as

```
fix g = g (g (g (g ....))))
```

where `g` is applied "infinitely many times". When `g` is a composition like `h . f` in this case, we obtain

```
fix (h . f) = h (f (h (f (h (f ...)))))
```

and, similarly,

```
fix (f . h) = f (h (f (h (f (h ...)))))
```

Now, since both applications are infinite, if we apply `h` on top of the second one we would expect to obtain the first one. In periodic numbers we have that `4.5(78)` is the same as `4.57(87)`, so the same intuition applies. In formulas,

```
h (fix (f . h)) = fix (h . f)
```

which is exactly the same law we wanted.

With monads, we can not compose things as easily if `f :: A -> M B` and `h :: B -> A`, since we need to use `fmap` here and there, and of course `mfix` instead of fix. We have

```
fmap h . f :: A -> M A
f . h      :: B -> M B
```

so both are candidate for `mfix`. To apply the "top-level" `h` after the `mfix` we also need to `fmap` it since `mfix` returns `M A`. We then obtain

```
mfix (fmap h . f) = fmap h (mfix (f . h))
```

Now, the above reasoning is not completely rigorous, but I believe it can be properly formalized in domain theory so to make sense even from a mathematical / theoretical point of view.

Answer (score 5):

### MonadFix Sliding Law

Unfortunately, the link you provided has an incorrect description of the sliding law. It states:

```
mfix (fmap h . f) = fmap h (mfix (f . h)) -- for strict h
```

The actual sliding law is slightly different:

```
mfix (fmap h . f) = fmap h (mfix (f . h)), when f (h _|_) = f _|_
```

That is, the precondition is weaker than asking `h` to be strict. It simply asks `f (h _|_) = f _|_`. Note that if `h` is strict, then this precondition is automatically satisfied. (See below for that particular case.) The distinction is important in the monadic case, even though the corresponding law for `fix` does not have it:

```
fix (f . g) = f (fix (g . f)) -- holds without any conditions!
```

This is because the bind of the underlying monad is usually strict in its left argument, and hence "moving" things around can be observed. For details see Section 2.4 of [Value Recursion in Monadic Computations](https://leventerkok.github.io/papers/erkok-thesis.pdf).

### The strict `h` case

When `h` is strict, then the law actually directly follows from the parametricity theorem for the type `(A -> M A) -> M A`. This is established in [Section 2.6.4](https://leventerkok.github.io/papers/erkok-thesis.pdf), and in particular Corollary 2.6.12 of the same text. In a sense, this is the "boring" case: That is, all monads with an `mfix` satisfy it. (So, there isn't really a point in making that specific case a "law.")

With the weaker requirement of `f (h _|_) = f _|_` we get a more useful equation that lets us manipulate terms involving `mfix` as it is applied to functions that are compositions of regular monadic ones (i.e., `f` above) and pure ones (i.e., `h` above).

### Why do we care?

You can still ask, "why do we care about the sliding law?" @chi's answer provides the intuition. If you write the law using monadic bind, it becomes more clear. Here's the consequent in that notation:

```
mfix (\x -> f x >>= return . h) = mfix (f . h) >>= return .h
```

If you look at the left-hand side, we see that `return . h` is a central arrow (i.e., one that only affect the value but not the "monadic" part), and thus we'd expect to be able to "lift" it out of the right-hand side of the `>>=`. It turns out that this requirement is too much to ask for, for arbitrary `h`: It can be shown that many monads of practical interest does not posses such a definition of `mfix`. (Details: See [Corollary 3.1.7 in Chapter 3](https://leventerkok.github.io/papers/erkok-thesis.pdf).) But the weakened form where we only require `f (h _|_) = h _|_` is satisfied by many practical instances.

In pictures, the sliding law allows us to do the following transformation:

[image]

which gives us the intuition: We would like the monadic knot-tying to be applied to the "smallest" possible scope, allowing other computations to be rearranged/shuffled around as necessary. The sliding property tells us exactly when this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about MonadFix laws, but I have something to say about the first part of your question. `h` being strict does not entail that `f . h` is also strict. For example, take

```
h = (+ 1) :: Int -> Int
f x = Nothing :: Maybe Int
```

For all inputs `x`, `(f . h) x` returns `Nothing`, so `h` is never called. In case you are worried that my `h` is somehow not as strict as it looks, observe that

```
fmap undefined (mfix (f . undefined)) :: Maybe Int
```

also returns `Nothing`. My choice of `h` didn't matter, because `h` is never called at all.

Comment: Oh, right. Evaluation in Haskell is from the outside in. Hence, `f` can choose whether or not to evaluate its argument. Thanks for clarifying that.